# Project or Workspace specific Indentation in Xcode4

Tags: xcode4

Is there any way to setup different indentation values for a specific project or workspace?

I've started working on a new project that uses a different indentation level then I've been using, and I would love to be able to set a custom value for that project, or setup a workspace for it, so that I don't have to think about changing indentation values when moving between projects.  I've searched around but haven't had any luck finding any discussion about it.

I came across this question/answer: [Is it possible to set indent settings in Xcode per project (or per file, even)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3216426/215217) This is the exact same problem that I have, however the solution does not seem to be available in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the file inspector by choosing View > Utilities > File Inspector. Select the project file from the project navigator. Use the Text Settings section in the file inspector to set the indentation for the project.