# Fix indentation for entire project in Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, indentation, auto-indent, appcode

I've inherited a huge iOS project which is all using two-space indenting. I need that to be four-space indenting. I know that I can hit Ctrl+I per file, but I'm wondering whether Xcode (or AppCode, for that matter) has a means of re-indenting every source file in the entire project in one whack.

Failing that, I’m wondering how I might go about writing some sort of script (using Automator, or perhaps an Xcode plugin, or even something on the command line) to achieve this without going insane.

Comment: This is possibly outdated by now, but see if the answers in this thread can be of help; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216426/is-it-possible-to-set-indent-settings-in-xcode-per-project-or-per-file-even.

Comment: No good I’m afraid – the options there don’t actual re-factor anything, they just set project preferences and won’t modify code.

Comment: That's too bad... I guess you could download a trial version of JetBrains AppCode and let their code formatter do the job, then return to Xcode. Not the solution you were hoping for though, I'm sure x) https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/features/

Comment: Formatting/indentation/codestyle support in Xcode has always been (and continues to be) significantly lacking. I don't know how Apple does it.

Comment: Take a look at clang-format. It may be able to do what you're looking for. It's available in brew.

Comment: AppCode doesn't seem to do the job either, I have that on my machine and I can't find options that will ONLY indent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did manage this with AppCode in the end. We ended up doing a wider-scale refactor using AppCode’s various tools. I’m not sure if I would’ve been able to do JUST the spacing, their Twitter support suggested that I could, but didn’t detail exactly how.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [SwiftFormat](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat) to make indentation on all of your project .swift files

```
$ brew install swiftformat
$ cd <path to your project>
$ swiftformat .
```

Comment: Should be accepted answer. Nice little tool.

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring and Re-Indenting are quite different operations. I'm making this distinction so that folks newer to coding / coding IDEs aren't confused.

**Refactoring:** taking an existing variable / block of code and propagating changes through the project where it is used. For example, refactoring (renaming) a variable foobar to foobar2 would automatically find all cases where foobar is used and change it to foobar2

**Re-indenting:** changing the structure / flow / alignment of the code to match the desired coding style for clarity / correctness, particularly ensuring that nested items like conditionals and loops are neatly aligned to improve code readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SourceKit](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/main/tools/SourceKit), but it is a bit complicated to use, so instead you can use [SourceKitten](https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten) which is a wrapper on top of SourceKit.
You have to search for all `.swift` files and run `sourcekitten format --file path/to/file`

```
find . -type f -name "*.swift" | while read line; do
  sourcekitten format --file "$line";
done
```