# Code indentation messed up after pushing to github

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10, xcode10.1

The code indentation looks absolutely fine in my Xcode. But when I push it to github, it screws up the indentation

[image]

Does anybody know why? The weird thing is everything looks fine in Xcode. I tried to change Xcode Preferences, **Ctrl + I**, but none of them works. Any help would be appreciated. I'm using Xcode 10.1 and here are my Preferences Settings

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use indent with space instead of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough, in Xcode Preferences, switching **Prefer indent using** to **Spaces** and switch it back to **Tabs** seems to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can set indentation per file, group, project, see how to change your indentation settings here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023275/1845432

It works for me

After changing your indentations settings, don't forget to reformat your files to apply the change.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>: to select all

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>: to fix code indentation

Answer (score -1):

I have it like this below and it works just fine with github.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your setting is quite similar to mine. I think it's a Xcode bug. Switching the prefer indent to **Spaces** and back to **Tabs** seems to fix the issue.

Comment: "This are my settings an they work" hardly qualifies as an answer. Especially, when your settings, in all relevant areas, are exactly the same as the OP's.